# Generating embedding for long documents using pre-trained word vectors

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, word-embedding, sentence-similarity

I have a set of pre-trained word embeddings from the Wikipedia corpus. I also have 300 dimension embeddings of Wikipedia article pages. I am looking to build a similarity engine by running a simple cosine similarity algorithm for any new query (long documents) against these pre-trained embeddings. To do this, I want to represent any new input document as a 300d vector using the pre-trained word embeddings and then run cosine similarity against the corpus. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [doc2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) model for representing documents as a vector. It is a generalizing of the word2vec method.